# "search.in" support for Azure Search 2016-09-01

Tags: azure-search

I get this error after query `$filter=ancestors/any(t: search.in(t, 'region:1014') )`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: search.in. This function is not supported in this API version.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}
```

With version 2015-02-28-Preview it work but with my version 2016-09-01 it doesn't work.

My document (entities)  is this 
 [[image: DOCUMENT DB[1]]

And would like to know how to filter entities that have ancestor that contains value for ex. "AA","NN". for version 2016-09-01.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 8.2 Update-3 and later require the 2015-02-28 schema version unless the `ContentSearch.Azure.UseIsMatchScoring` setting is set to false.

Note, however that this restricts functionality - possibly including your query, per the description of that setting:

```
USE ISMATCHSCORING
Determines if Azure Search provider uses ismatchscoring() function to build complex search expressions. 
This function is available in version 2015-02-28-Preview of Azure Search API and is not available in version 2016-09-01 or earlier versions. 
When using Azure Search API version 2016-09-01 or earlier versions, this setting must be changed to false. 
Changing the value to false will limit the support for complex search queries.

Default value: true
```

Comment: Hello my query is this: {
  "search": "8001 S Orange Blossom",
  "filter": "entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t: t in 'region:1094','store:1100') or entity_id eq 'region:1094')",
  "count": "true"
  
} and got now this error  {
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: ')' or ',' expected at position 47 in 'entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t: t in 'region:1094','store:1100') or entity_id eq 'region:1094')'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
} thank you